# Adding mouse scroll effect to html "range" element (with step movements only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to build a scroll element that is independent from the scrolling window and then trigger some events in the window based on events on this independent scrollbar.

Only option that i could think of was to create a vertical input type="range" element.

Here's my progress so far (there is a small slider on right side of window): https://jsfiddle.net/xerxes3117/3v1xdjse/4/

**HTML:**

```
 <p>
    <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="25" step="1" value="0" orient="vertical">
</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .slider {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 270px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #d3d3d3;
        outline: none;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s;
    }

    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 5px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #283e3e;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="range"] {
        transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-140px, 480px);
    }
```

**JS:**

```
//Width and height
    var w = 600;
    var h = 250;

    var dataset = [{
            key: 0,
            value: 5
        }, //dataset is now an array of objects.
        {
            key: 1,
            value: 10
        }, //Each object has a 'key' and a 'value'.
        {
            key: 2,
            value: 13
        },
        {
            key: 3,
            value: 19
        },
        {
            key: 4,
            value: 21
        },
        {
            key: 5,
            value: 25
        },
        {
            key: 6,
            value: 22
        },
        {
            key: 7,
            value: 18
        },
        {
            key: 8,
            value: 15
        },
        {
            key: 9,
            value: 13
        },
        {
            key: 10,
            value: 11
        },
        {
            key: 11,
            value: 12
        },
        {
            key: 12,
            value: 15
        },
        {
            key: 13,
            value: 20
        },
        {
            key: 14,
            value: 18
        },
        {
            key: 15,
            value: 17
        },
        {
            key: 16,
            value: 16
        },
        {
            key: 17,
            value: 18
        },
        {
            key: 18,
            value: 23
        },
        {
            key: 19,
            value: 25
        }
    ];

    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
        .rangeRound([0, w])
        .paddingInner(0.05);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
            return d.value;
        })])
        .range([0, h]);

    //Define key function, to be used when binding data
    var key = function(d) {
        return d.key;
    };

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    //Create bars
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset, key)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return xScale(i);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d.value);
        })
        .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.value);
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.value * 10) + ")";
        });

    //Create labels
    svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(dataset, key)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
        })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("fill", "white");




    //On change, update styling
    d3.select("input")
        .on("change", function() {

            var threshold = +d3.select(this).node().value;

            test = d3.select(this).node().value;

            console.log("threshold = ", threshold);
            console.log("test = ", test);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
                .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.value * 10) + ")";
                })
                .filter(function(d) {
                    return d.value <= threshold;
                })
                .attr("fill", "red");

        });
```

However, i am facing 2 issues in this slider :

1. On any event (drag, click, scroll) i want this to move by 1 step only. As an example if i click somewhere in the middle of slider window it goes directly to that position. However, I want to move by one step only (up or down) no matter where in the window i click
2. Currently, the slider moves only on click and drag but not on scroll (mouse wheel). I want this element to move on scroll also.

Any existing projects/demos which showcase the above functionalities are welcome. Also, let me know if there are any other options than using input type="range" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated JS Fiddle. Just use d3.zoom event on the svg and change the curent Step.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v1xdjse/40/)

```
 //Width and height
 var w = 600;
 var h = 250;
 var curentStep = 0
 var dataset = [{
     key: 0,
     value: 5
   }, //dataset is now an array of objects.
   {
     key: 1,
     value: 10
   }, //Each object has a 'key' and a 'value'.
   {
     key: 2,
     value: 13
   },
   {
     key: 3,
     value: 19
   },
   {
     key: 4,
     value: 21
   },
   {
     key: 5,
     value: 25
   },
   {
     key: 6,
     value: 22
   },
   {
     key: 7,
     value: 18
   },
   {
     key: 8,
     value: 15
   },
   {
     key: 9,
     value: 13
   },
   {
     key: 10,
     value: 11
   },
   {
     key: 11,
     value: 12
   },
   {
     key: 12,
     value: 15
   },
   {
     key: 13,
     value: 20
   },
   {
     key: 14,
     value: 18
   },
   {
     key: 15,
     value: 17
   },
   {
     key: 16,
     value: 16
   },
   {
     key: 17,
     value: 18
   },
   {
     key: 18,
     value: 23
   },
   {
     key: 19,
     value: 25
   }
 ];

 var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
   .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
   .rangeRound([0, w])
   .paddingInner(0.05);

 var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
     return d.value;
   })])
   .range([0, h]);

 //Define key function, to be used when binding data
 var key = function(d) {
   return d.key;
 };

 function zoomFunction() {
   if (d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY > 0) {
     if (curentStep > 0) {
       curentStep--
     }
   } else {
     if (curentStep < 25) {
       curentStep++
     }
   }
   stepChange()
 }
 var zoom = d3.zoom()
   .on("zoom", zoomFunction);
 //Create SVG element
 var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h)
   .call(zoom);

 //Create bars
 svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset, key)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return xScale(i);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d.value);
   })
   .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
   .attr("height", function(d) {
     return yScale(d.value);
   })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
     return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.value * 10) + ")";
   });

 //Create labels
 svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset, key)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
     return d.value;
   })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d.value) + 14;
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white");


 function stepChange() {
   d3.select("input").node().value = curentStep
   svg.selectAll("rect")
     .attr("fill", function(d) {
       return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.value * 10) + ")";
     })
     .filter(function(d) {
       return d.value <= curentStep;
     })
     .attr("fill", "red");
   //console.log(d3.select("#curentStep").node().text = c)
   d3.select("#curentStep").node().textContent = curentStep
   //d3.select("#curentStep").node().innerHtml = curentStep
 }


 //On change, update styling
 d3.select("input")
   .on("change", function() {
     var threshold = d3.select(this).node().value;
     if (threshold > curentStep) {
       curentStep++
     } else if (threshold < curentStep) {
       curentStep--
     }
     console.log("threshold = ", threshold);
     stepChange()
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... this works nicely ... is there any way to remove the effect that is being displayed initially (scroller goes to a point and then displaces to step position) and make it feel like the scroller is moving one step only

Comment: Try changing the `on("change")` event to `on("input")`. That'll make it look like the scroll moving by one step.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3v1xdjse/46/ here is the updated fiddle. Can you accept the answer?

Comment: cool this is awesome ... thanks a lot ... let me try something similar for part 2 (moving this element on mouse scroll) .. i want to make this as close as possible to a normal scroller ... can you please tell me which on(" ") event i need to trigger for 1) mouse wheel scroll 2) clicking while holding (i.e. not letting go the left click)

Comment: ask new question for new problem :)

Comment: Hey Tobias, could you please explain how the d3.zoom part and functions are working here ... i've never used the d3.zoom so i'm a bit confused there ... also can we apply the same functionality over a d3 brush element for discrete brushing? .... thanks for your help